# Create directory without manage all files permission

Tags: java, android, file, permissions

How can i create directory in `( /storage/emulated/0/ )` without manage all files permission.
This is my code :

```js
        File myFolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"testDir");
        if(!myFolder.exists() || myFolder.isFile()){
            if(myFolder.isFile()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'testDir' exists as file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            try{
                myFolder.mkdir();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Directories created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
```

On android 11 its not working because it need manage all files permission.

Comment: `data / 0 / emulated /` There is no such path. And certainly not with all those spaces. Instead there is `/storage/emulated/0` as root of external storage.

Comment: I fixed it and that how can i make a folder without manage all files permission

Comment: You cant. Make your own folder in one of the public directories like Documents, Download, DCIM, Pictures and so on.

Comment: But there is an app that does it without asking for permission manage all files

Comment: `myFolder.mkdir();` Better: `if (!myFolder.exists()) if (!myFolder.mkdir()) return;` That try-catch is useless as mkdir() will not throw.

Comment: And you will not tell wich app. Well ok.

Comment: And your app can too if you let the user create such a directory using SAF and ACTION_,OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: App name is scanpet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SDK 30 you can not access all file system without using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

If your app is in following categories you can ask for this permission:

- File management
- Backup and restore apps
- Anti-virus apps
- Document management apps
- Search (On Device)
- Disk/Folder Encryption and Locking
- Device Migration/Phone transfer

ref: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-all-files-access-permission

If your app is photo, video editing app or something like this than in that case you don't need this permission. You can simply use SAF or media directory like DCIM, Downloads, Videos etc...and create your folder there to save your images, videos etc. other way, you can use Android/ media or data folder.